# How to convert csv file to avro file format using avro-tools jar?

Tags: java, csv, avro

I want to convert CSV file to Avro. Currently I am converting my CSV to json and then creating Avro file out of it. Below is the sample CSV data,

```
name,favorite_number,favorite_color
Rick,26,Red
Mathew,22,Blue
```

Is there a direct way to convert CSV file to Avro using avro-tools?
can fromtext do the job?

```
d:\app>java -jar avro-tools-1.7.7.jar fromtext
Expected 2 args: from_file to_file (local filenames, Hadoop URI's, or '-' for st
din/stdout
Option                                  Description
------                                  -----------
--codec                                 Compression codec (default: null)
--level <Integer>                       Compression level (only applies to
                                      deflate and xz) (default: -1)
```

I have read the solutions achieved using hive. **Please note** - I'm not using Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Avro Tools' `fromtext` will convert the file so that each record corresponds to a whole line, which is not what you want. [Csv2avro](https://github.com/sspinc/csv2avro) seems to be the tool you are looking for. [This blog post](http://garrens.com/blog/2015/03/21/converting-csvs-with-headers-to-avro/) mentions two similar tools, but they seem to be less mature.

Comment: Can you please share examples for Avro tool's `fromtext`